# how does the initState access the context?

Tags: flutter, dart

can anyone tell why  this giv me an error when I place the CountProvider out side the initState and build function and error go way when I place the CountProvider inside the initState and it also outside the build function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFGsD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8MUU.png)

and the error is[ The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression ]

Comment: Please post code, not an image of the code.

Comment: Agreed! It is understandable that you want to show visuals of what want explanation for and not some code edits due to the nature of the question, but please do attach code to your question for improved clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html#:%7E:text=The%20framework%20associates%20State%20objects%20with%20a%20BuildContext%20after%20creating%20them%20with%20StatefulWidget.createState%20and%20before%20calling%20initState)

> The framework associates State objects with a BuildContext after
> creating them with StatefulWidget.createState and before calling
> initState

So initState has access to the `context` of a Stateful Widget because between the creation of a State and the calling of initState, a BuildContext is already available to be passed.

So

1. The [State is created](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html#:%7E:text=State%20objects%20are%20created%20by%20the%20framework%20by%20calling%20the%20StatefulWidget.createState%20method%20when%20inflating%20a%20StatefulWidget%20to%20insert%20it%20into%20the%20tree) by StatefulWidget.createState

> State objects are created by the framework by calling the
> StatefulWidget.createState method when inflating a StatefulWidget to
> insert it into the tree.

2. A context is associated with the State.
3. The initState is called which also then gains access to the context.

[build](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html#:%7E:text=After%20calling%20initState.) is then called after initState and we have our render.

In that order, it is after the build has been called that any other method is called, so any such in your code may not have access to a context outside of the scope of an `initState` or a `build` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to declare a variable which you want to access in both initState method and build method. I think you may declare the variable globally and initialize it in initState method.

```
class_HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
var CountProvider; //Declare variable here

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    CountProvider = Provider.of<countProvider>(context, listen: false); // Initialize the variable here

    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 0), (timer) { 
        CountProvider.IncraceCount(); 
    }); // Timer.periodic
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
}
```